# Vim regex: match line except pattern

Tags: regex, vim

I have the following two lines:

```
test.tex|42 error| Undefined control sequence
test.tex|43 error| Undefined control sequenceFAILURE
```

I want a regex that matches  "Undefined control sequence" in both lines (thus ignoring the FAILURE part in the second line). I tried with

```
/^|\d\+ error|\s\zs.*
```

but that obviously highlights FAILURE too. I suppose I must use a negative lookahead but I'm using it wrong since the following doesn't work

```
/^|\d\+ error|\s\zs.*\(FAILURE\)\@!
```

**EDIT:** The "Undefined control sequence" is just a type of error. The generic structure of the lines is

```
 file|number error| Error message
```

I want a generic regex that matches only the error message that sometimes ends as

```
Error messsageFAILURE
```

I want to ignore the "FAILURE" part and just get the "Error message"

Comment: why `/Undefined control sequence` won't work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

for your question, `/Undefined control sequence` will work exactly what you wanted.

If you want to have some dynamic matching, you could try:

```
\verror\|\s\zs.{-}\ze(FAILURE|$)
```

Comment: I edited my question to clarify what I need. Your second regex kind of works but it also matches "error | " which I want to ignore.

Comment: @petobens there was a small mistake, I fixed it now. sorry.

Answer (score 0):

The pattern `/Undefined control sequence` will match both lines, while the pattern `/Undefined control sequence\>` will only match the first line since `\>` matches the end of a word.

Comment: Sorry, I misread the question. I have expanded my previous answer.